# Solidity Event String parameter decoding

Tags: solidity, web3.py, events, logs, decode

The value of `aggregatorId` in the event emitted by the below tx is not equal to value “oneInchV5FeeDynamic” in the tx? Also, I can’t decode the value emitted in the event “0xf35f348d53012d52a5d39f9390d246956ac932d5778d2bb49e359dba4fa0896d” into a string using `eth_abi` `abi.decode` method. 
The below method also returns value "0xf35f348d53012d52a5d39f9390d246956ac932d5778d2bb49e359dba4fa0896d".

```
processed_log = contract.events.myEvent().process_log(log_to_process)
```

The hex equivalent of string value “oneInchV5FeeDynamic” is “0x6f6e65496e6368563546656544796e616d6963”, which is not same as event emitted value. 
Can anyone explain this?

**Decoded tx data**

Name      |  Type      |  Data 
aggregatorId  |  string   |     oneInchV5FeeDynamic |
tokenFrom  |  address  |  0xA9E8aCf069C58aEc8825542845Fd754e41a9489A |
amount |   uint256  |  1891980133455368475347 |
data   |     bytes  |      0x000000000000000000000000a9e8acf06… |

**Emitted event**

Name
Swap (index_topic_1 string aggregatorId, index_topic_2 address sender)

Topics 
0 - 0xbeee1e6e7fe307ddcf84b0a16137a4430ad5e2480fc4f4a8e250ab56ccd7630d
1 - 0xf35f348d53012d52a5d39f9390d246956ac932d5778d2bb49e359dba4fa0896d (value of aggregatorId) 
2 - 0x748dF7c92687A7acA7c1ac81b1cDC2A3995581b9\

Answer (score 0):

If the topic is of string type, the string value returned by the log is keccak256(bytes("oneInchV5FeeDynamic")). Try not to mark strings as topics.

Comment: I am working on a tool that uses static analysis to extract the complete state of the Solidity smart contract. And I have noticed that many "Router" contracts do this, and I am facing issues in getting value of mapping key from event's indexed string parameter.
This tx is of MetaSwap (Metamask: Swap Router) smart contract.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xea67463f6720a444fdcd6248b130c1f08c4efc8760a47591ea3875c35c3b5cbe